# In AngularJs when trying to delete a row after sorting, the wrong row gets deleted. Which is according to id. How will I write the code to solve

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
   **html part**

<div>
            <p>search :
                <input type="search" ng-model="customer" placeholder="search for customers" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Sort by:
                <select ng-model="orderCustomer">
                  <option value="custId">Customer ID</option>
                  <option value="name">Name</option>
                  <option value="phone">Phone Number</option>
                  <option value="pan">Pan ID</option>
                  <option value="customerTypeName">Customer Type</option>
                  <option value="createdOn">Created Date</option>
                  <option value="createdBy">Created By</option>
                  <option value="lastUpdatedOn">Updated On</option>
                  <option value="lastUpdatedBy">Updated By</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <hr />
        {{error}} {{' Total # of Customers = '+ customers.length}}
        <hr />
        <%-- {{'Total # of Selected Customers = 'selected.length}}--%>
        <hr />
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkAll()" ng-model="checkAll.isCheckAll"  /></th>
                    <th>Sl no</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>PAN</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>CreatedOn</th>
                    <th>CreatedBy</th>
                    <th>LastUpdatedOn</th>
                    <th>LastUpdatedBy</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr
                    ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:customer | orderBy:orderCustomer">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.checked" ng-click="checkedIndex(customers)">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.custId }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.phone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.pan }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.customerTypeName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.createdOn }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.createdBy }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.lastUpdatedOn }}</td>
                    <td>{{ customer.lastUpdatedBy }}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="removeRow(idx)">X</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
**js part**
            $scope.removeRow = function (idx) {
              $scope.customers.splice(idx, 1);
            };
```

If I'm using this jscript to splice then after sorting the values, the if try to delete the data from rows then the wrong rows get deleted every time.
And if I sort it to custId then delete button works fine?
Can anyone help me in this?
Here is similar kind of program from plunker [plunker code, You can search for mojombo, h, or anyother](http://plnkr.co/edit/heqBVZAKw4bbeTcshyqJ?p=preview).
Its a API from github https://api.github.com/users

Another thing if I select all rows and try delete button Its also not working.
Can anyone help me in this. I'm totally new to angularjs.

Comment: That plunker is not for your code right? Create one with your code.

Comment: You should pass `$index` in the `removeRow` method. Eg: 
`<td><button ng-click="removeRow($index)">X</button></td>`

Comment: No actually, this is another code. But a similar kind of code I have done and given the link(plunker).

Answer (score 2):

Dont do the delete by index 
please find the index of the object by custId and then using that object remove from array
As

```
<td><button ng-click="removeRow(customer)">X</button></td>

$scope.removeRow = function (customer) {
      var index = customers.findIndex(x => x.custId ==customer.custId);
      $scope.customers.splice(index, 1);
};
$scope.removeRows = function () {
    $scope.customers = $scope.customers.filter(i=>i.checked==false);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `removeRow(idx)` should be `removeRow($index)`

Comment: after that also it is not working...You can try it in the plunker if you like. I have given the link

Answer (score 1):

> Another thing if I select all rows and try delete button Its also not working. Can anyone help me in this. I'm totally new to angularjs.

For this to work I guess you should have a common delete button outside of all the rows and implement a function like this

```js
$scope.removeRows = function () { 
 /* Iterate through $scope.customers and remove all checked one*/

};
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:customer | orderBy:orderCustomer">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.checked" ng-click="checkedIndex(customers)">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.custId }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.phone }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.pan }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.customerTypeName }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.createdOn }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.createdBy }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.lastUpdatedOn }}</td>
      <td>{{ customer.lastUpdatedBy }}</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<button ng-click="removeRows()">X</button>
```